# JPA2 lock mode issue

Tags: java, mysql, locking, persistence, jpa-2.0

Dear friends i'm trying to use lock mode on my webApp with Mysql and JPA2 persitence. I want to lock a record with PESSIMISTIC.WRITE mode so if a user A is trying to modify a record, and in the same time a user B try to modify the same record, a message could appear and says "This record is in use. Retry later" . To do that I have a datatable and when a user want to modify a record, he can select it and click on "Edit Button", then i have this code :

```
public void setLockMode(Nominativi nom) {
    //Nominativi nom is the record that user selected from datatable
    Nominativi n=em.find(Nominativi.class, nom.getIdnominativi(), LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);       
}
```

So user A see a dialog page where he can modify the records value. After that click on "save Button" and have this code:

```
public void update(Nominativi nom) {
    em.merge(nom);
    em.flush();
}
```

I know that after flush() the record is no longer locked and is available for other users.
So when I try to edit the same record from 2 different session ( 2 different browser on the same PC) I can edit the record simoultaneously with no  fired exception. Where is my fault ? Can I simulate the simoultaneos behaviour using 2 different browser session on the same PC ?

Comment: Does your persistence context have the right scope?

Comment: I never specified it, so i think it's the default ( transaction ). This could be a problem ?

Comment: I don't know, just guessing here; maybe the interleaving of the two sessions is such that when the second one is started, the first one is finished already, releasing the lock?

Comment: If you use Java EE, do you use `@Stateful` EJBs for your user sessions?

Comment: No they are all @Stateless.....

Comment: So do setLockMode() and update() happen within the same request? Since you said the user presses a button first and only saves changes after finishing the modifications, it sounds like they don't? In that case, the transaction would have finished after the first request, releasing the lock ...?

Comment: All steps happen in a @SessionScoped bean, so I think that this isn't the problem. I try with optimistic lock with version field and all work well, so I don't understand where is the problem with the pessimistic lock.